# Does scala play 1.2.4 have compatibility with postgres?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, scala, playframework

There are so many horror stories about postgres and Play framework here on SO and on blogs.
So I am wondering does Play 1.2.4, scala and anrom(magic) work with postgres or not.

In my test case I get the following when switching to `Postgres`.

[image: Error]

The db is correctly created by 1.sql in evolutions. And the log prints `Connected to jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres_play`

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: @Dave I usually do that but in this case I think that the play framework has condensed a much better error description than I would in asci.

Comment: I disagree; the stack trace is sufficient, and textual.

Answer (score 1):

Anorm works just fine with postgresql, we're currently converting a complex postgresql based app from PHP to play with scala and have had no DB related issues at all.  As to your error, I'm not 100% certain but it may be simply that it is looking for the table "Player" and you have the table "player" in your database.  Show us the code where you are defining the Player object that extends magic.